# Will AWS charge me for the wait time on a step function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Currently i have a state machine that receives two parameters as input.

```json
{
  "tte": "2021-09-22T12:53:56.343571Z",
  "message": "Hello world"
}
```

When starting, the first step is to wait for the time determined by the `tte` (time to execute) attribute. Finally send the content of the `message` attribute to a queue in sqs.

I understand that aws charges me for changes in the status of my machine, but I have no idea if a long waiting time, for example 1 week, could incur additional costs?

Answer (score 2):

No there is no hidden costs in addition to state transitions.
https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/pricing/

And AWS Step Functions is the cheapest service in AWS for waiting. you can wait up to 1 year by using Wait state or WaitForTaskToken without any cost.

Comment: Thanks, it is the solution that I liked the most to glue jobs with a quota of more than one day. I only fear for the costs, but I am already calmer.